# Want my table to refresh when new content is added to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For the moment I have an ajax-function that gets the information I need, but I have to refresh it manually when new content is added.
My code looks like this for the moment:

```
<script>
$(function (){

 $(function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "info.php",
        type:"get",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var clean = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(clean, function(i){
                var t = new Date(clean[i]['upplagd']);
                var tid = (t.getDate() + " / "+ (t.getMonth()+1) + " / " + t.getFullYear());
                var table = $('tbody').html();
                $('tbody').html(table + '<tr><td><img src="img/' + clean[i]['bild'] + '"></td><td>' + 
                    clean[i]['titel'] + "<br><b>" + clean[i]['kund'] + "</b></td><td>" + 
                    clean[i]['kommun'] + "</td><td>" + 
                    tid + "</td></tr>");
           }    
    }); 
});
});
</script>
```

So, it gets the information and prints it out. Quite simple.
This is my php-page when AJAX gets its information.

```
    <?php
       header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
       header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GTM");

       $database = "database";
       $server = "localhost";
       $user = "root";
       $pass = "pass";

       $db = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$database);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM xterna";
       $array = [];

         $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                 $row_arr['id'] = $row['id'];
                 $row_arr['kommun'] = $row['kommun'];
                 $row_arr['kund'] = $row['kund'];
                 $row_arr['titel'] = $row['titel'];
                 $row_arr['upplagd'] = $row['upplagd'];
                 $row_arr['bild'] = $row['bild'];
                 array_push($array,$row_arr);
         }

      $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

       echo $json;
       ?>
```

I know that you can use setinterval and call on the function, but when I do that it gives me everything instead of just one data.
Anyone know a simple code or anything?

Comment: Redirect back to the current page when new content is added

Comment: The project is for a company that are hiring people. So I want the table to update for the users (the ones applying), without reloading the page. The users themselves wont upload any content, so they don't know when new content is added. Sorry if I'm bad at describing, I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: You might want to have a read about server sent events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: This is quite unclear `but when I do that it gives me everything instead of just one data`, you want to refresh your table however, you only want to return one data? Im confused, sorry

Comment: You are on the right way. If `$row_arr['id']` is the primary key, save the highest ID as Javascript var. Just execute another asynchronous request with `setInterval()` and deliver the highest primary key you 've got with the last request. With the delivered primary key execute the db query like `... WHERE id > $delivered_id`.

Comment: why not use websockets?

Comment: @Roljhon sorry for being unclear. At the moment, with my setInterval, I get every cell, all the rows from my database. I just want the most recent one, but I get all of them.

Comment: @Marcel thank you, I'll see and check on this. Much appreciated!

Comment: @SebbeBerglönn well, the idea is to limit your sql query to return only 1 and set your order by to descending. Remove the while loop and fetch one time. Return the data to the user, append the new data from your table. I think that's what you want? that's the logic I am thinking.

Comment: Hey bud, this isn't as complicated as everyone is making it.  Just have the PHP file return the HTML snip with the data already in it.  Put the new HTML in the appropriate div.  No need to even use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that HTTP is not full-duplex bidirectional communication channel so the is no obvious way to inform the browser that there is an update on the database, but there are multiple solution to that:
**1- check the server periodically**
in this solution you send an HTTP request periodically after a certain time and the server will respond with the updates if any. I don't recommend this approach for performance issues.

**2- long polling**
which is basically to send an HTTP request to the server then the server will hold the request open until there is a new update after that the server will return the response with the updates then send another request and so on.
**3- Websockets**
websockets is a new feature was bundled with HTML5 where the browser can open a full-duplex bidirectional communication channel to the server where the server can send updates to the client without the need of repetitive sending an HTTP request to check for new update.